# How do i put the degree(°) symbol in a Label in GWT

Tags: gwt, gxt

I tried to just copy and paste it but when i try to run the program it shows up like this, �. Just wondering if there is a way to do it.

Comment: Are you sure you're using UTF-8 everywhere? Doctype, file encoding, etc.?

Comment: Im using UTF-8   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: And the actual encoding of the file is UTF-8?

Comment: Could you post your code so we can understand better your problem? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the cleanest is to encode it as HTML character entity: `&deg;`. This doesn't work in `Label`, but it does for instance in `HTML` which is practically a drop-in replacement for `Label`:

```
new HTML("10&deg;C");
```

instead of

```
new Label("10&deg;C");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use unicode notation:

```
new Label("Hello \u00b0 there!")
```